# Node dependency container doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, node-modules

I have a DI container like this:

```
# di-container.js
const container = {
    fileReader: require("./file-reader"),
    csvReader: require("./csv-reader"),
}

module.exports = {
    container
}
```

And `csv-reader.js` looks like this:

```
# csv-reader.js
const { container } = require("./di-container")

async function readFileAsCSV(path)
    const fileContents = await container.fileReader.readFileContents(path)
    return fileContents.split("\n")
                       .map(line => line.split(","))
}
```

I have a test file `csv-reader.spec.js`:

```
# csv-reader.spec.js
const { container } = require("./di-container")

describe("csvReader", () => {
    it("should read cells from file", async () => {
        const fakeCSV = "\"Name\",\"Age\"\n\"Bob Smith\",\"32\""
        container.fileReader.readFileContents = (_) => fakeCSV

        const result = container.csvReader.readFileAsCSV()

        # Do some assertions...
    })
})
```

When running the test it fails with the error (stack trace line numbers different as the example is slightly different):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileReader' of undefined
 at Object.readFileAsCSV (csv-reader.js:8:42)
 at Context.it (csv-reader.spec.js:15:44)
 at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:443:21)
```

I expected that the memory reference to `container` is the same in `csv-reader.spec.js` and `csv-reader.js`, so I should be able to change `container.fileReader.readFileContents` and `csv-reader` will use the mock function.

If I remove the `csvReader: require("./csv-reader")` line from `di-container.js` and use `const csvReader = require("./csv-reader")` in `csv-reader.spec.js`, then the test passes. This would suggest some oddity with the order in which the dependencies in `container` are being created.

I have tried rearranging the order of `fileReader` and `csvReader` in `container`, and changing them to be like `container.fileReader = ...` instead of inline instantiation but that did not work.jav

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency [module cycle](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

Your `di-container.js` file requires `csv-reader.js` and `csv-reader.js` file requires `di-container.js` which forms a cycle.

Because of this, `require("./di-container")` returns `null` inside the `csv-reader.js` file.
Because `require("./di-container")` is `null`, The destructured `container` will be undefined.
And thus, your are getting the error which you mentioned.

You need to redesign your functions and might want to think about where do you want to put them.

---

On very broad level, just separate out the functions which are to be used in both the files and put them inside `common.js`

Then, require `common.js` inside `csv-reader.js` and `di-container.js`

---

> If I remove the csvReader: require("./csv-reader") line from
>   di-container.js and use const csvReader = require("./csv-reader") in
>   csv-reader.spec.js, then the test passes. This would suggest some
>   oddity with the order in which the dependencies in container are being
>   created.

The cycle broke once you did not require `csv-reader.js` from the `di-container.js` and hence it is working just fine.